# Is the first term of this sequence the greatest?

Tags: number-theory

Let $(u_{n})_{n\geqslant 0}$ the sequence defined by $\displaystyle{u_{n}=\dfrac{2}{\log^{2}\dfrac{p_{n+2}^{2}+3}{2}}\prod_{i=2}^{n+2}\dfrac{p_{i}}{p_{i}-2}}$ where $p_{k}$ is the $k$-th prime number.

Is it true that $u_{0}$ is the greatest term of this sequence?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does $\log^2x$ denote $\log\log x$ or $(\log x)^2$?

Comment: Sorry, it denotes $(\log x)^{2}$. $\log\log x$ is, most of the time, denoted by $\log_{2}x$.

Comment: @Sylvain I have never seen that notation used that way - subscripts $\log_b$ usually denote logarithms with base $b$ in my experience.

Comment: I'm also assuming that the base is $e$, but since you seem to use notation in a nonstandard way I'd like to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The claim is plausible. I will show that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{2}{\log^2 \frac{p_{n+2}^2+2}{3}} \prod_{i=2}^{n+2} \frac{p_i}{p_i-2}\approx  0.600 < u_1 \approx 1.436$$

Set $P = p_{n+2}$. We focus on computing the product
$$X:= \prod_{3 \leq p \leq P} \frac{p}{p-2}$$
We have
$$X = \prod_{3 \leq p \leq P} \left( \frac{(1-1/p)^2}{1-2/p} \right) \cdot \prod_{3 \leq p \leq P} \left( 1-\frac{1}{p}\vphantom{\frac{(1-1/p)^2}{1-2/p}} \right)^{-2}$$
The product $\prod_{p \geq 3} \left( \frac{(1-1/p)^2}{1-2/p} \right)$ is convergent; I don't know a closed form for it but numerical computation suggests that is roughly $1.514$. By [Mertens' theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MertensTheorem.html), the second term is $(1/4) (e^{\gamma} \log P)^2 \approx 0.793 \log^2 P$. (The $1/4$ is because of the missing term at $p=2$.) So
$$X \approx 1.514 \times 0.793 \log^2 P \approx 1.201 \log^2 P.$$

Now 
$$\frac{2}{\log^2\frac{P^2+2}{3}} = \frac{2}{\left( 2 \log P + O(1) \right)^2} \sim \frac{1}{2 \log^2 P}.$$
So your ratio is
$$\frac{2}{\log^2\frac{P^2+2}{3}} X \approx \frac{1}{2 \log^2 P} \left(1.201 \log^2 P \right) \approx 0.600$$

There should be no obstacle in principle to turning these estimates into precise bounds which would allow you to prove that this is true for all $n$ past a finite bound, and then check this finite number of cases by hand.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It should be possible to prove rigorously that the limit of my ratio is $\dfrac{e^{2\gamma}}{8C_{2}}$ with $C_{2}$ the twin prime constant (analogous calculations on another math forum were performed several years ago but it'll take some time to find them again).